# Is there a public API I could connect to with JDBC and issue queries?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I'm trying to find a URL I could connect to in building a demo app for teaching purposes.

Anyone aware of one I could use with JDBC?

Answer (score 2):

You could probably set up a database in a local file and connect to that via JDBC.

Two examples of database drivers that are freely available are:

- [SQLite Java](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/), to connect to SQLite databases.
- [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html), to connect to MS Access databases.

Then you can connect to it via JDBC like this:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite://<db file path>");
// or
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://<mdb or accdb file path>");
```

The respective links contain more in-depth tutorials.

You can connect to a file and then set up the database via Java by executing SQL statements. The result is persisted in the file, which you could then use and redistribute for teaching.